# Is it possible to have webform-civicrm allow 'user select' for the Contribution page so user can select Currency?

Tags: webform-civicrm, contribution-page, currency

We have a situation where we need folk to be able to choose currency. currently this means multiple Contribution pages.

I was hoping we could redo this using Webform-civicrm and set the Contribution Page as 'user selects'.

This is not currently a valid setting.

Any obvious reasons why this would be difficult to accomplish?

Or is there another way to offer 'currency' directly?

Comment: Did you try it with webform conditionals? And assign all the contribution pages to the webform?

Comment: I don't follow how to do this. The 'contribution page' field is a 'single select' currently. How could I 'assign all contribution pages' to the webform? keen to learn. only way i see of doing this is multiple webforms

Comment: I assumed one could assign multiple contribution pages to a webform.

Comment: One way i could think is to use general webform-select field for list of currencies, in form_alter hook setup form_validate function then in form_validate function use user submitted currency value to setup currency in contribution page section.

Answer (score 0):

> Or is there another way to offer 'currency' directly?

On latest Webform CiviCRM 6.x, you get an option to select currency directly from Contribution Tab

[image]